# how to access elements in the print dialogue window from javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to access the print button in the print dialogue window (the window that comes up when you press `Ctrl` + `P`):

[image]

I tried `document.getElementsByClassName('action-button')` but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The print dialogue isn't in the DOM of your document, it's a separate document.

Comment: Notice that it's in a `#shadow-root`. It's like an iframe.

Comment: I don’t think you can or should try to access that.

Comment: Security reasons would of course forbid this, can you imagine going to a not so family friendly website, and the website doing a `window.print` and then physically printing.. :)